# How to convert math formulae in spectacular fonts into MS Word easily?

Tags: fonts, miktex, conversion

I wrote an article in LaTeX, but have to convert it to Word. It is not hard to copy text into Word, but for formulae, it is another story since they are in source codes mode in TeX files whereas in display mode in Word files.

Laeqed has solved some problems, but there is one remains: I have used some packages such as MnSymbol, yfonts. However fonts of these do not be contained in Windows...

---

Update:

I have solved the problem above, but need a better methodology that need not to regenerate all formulae involved one by one once change a font.

Comment: If you need TeX math features not available in Word, I guess the only way would be to generate an image (eg, png) of the TeX formula and pasting it into word. Not that I'm recommending this way, but perhaps it is the only possible.

Comment: @JLDiaz Well, Laeqed works in this way, fortunately it allows packages, but whenever I want to change a font, I have to regenerate all formulae involved, then paste them manually.

Comment: use `TeX2Word` (http://www.chikrii.com/products/tex2word/tex-to-word/)

Comment: I've built a very nice sport car, but now I have to convert it into a truck, how can I do? (Change the roles of "sport car" and "truck", if you prefer.) Both objects have their importance and use, but it's not easy to transform one into the other.

Comment: @Herbert It works! However for the reason lacking informations of some fonts, returned garbled... So I think I should install fonts firstly.

Comment: @Popopo [mathtype](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) can do its best in word and also [export to LaTeX](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/features.htm#export_to_tex). See [grindeq](http://www.grindeq.com/). LaTeX and Word are two different world's, better don't try join them. Hence all methods will not work 100%.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the equation editor of MS Word 2007 (or above). It is in general not possible to change the default font "Cambria Math" used in the "math region". However, somebody seemed to have come up with a hackish work-around: see Guthrix's reply in [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/setting-equations-in-word-2010-with-font-different/52cd720c-24dc-4824-9b31-87f368a368ab).