# Converting Powerpoint master slide to beamer

Tags: beamer, powerpoint

Is it possible to take a Powerpoint master slide and convert it to something that can be used with beamer? My organization requires the use of Powerpoint, but I can get away with presenting pdf's provided that the looks are the same. (I've seen several posts that talk about going from beamer to Powerpoint, but not in the opposite direction.)

Comment: Yes in theory similar to egreg's [apt analogy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102286/how-to-convert-math-formulae-in-spectacular-fonts-into-ms-word-easily#comment222544_102286).I suggest go with PowerPoint with your organisation,i am sure you cannot fool the Quality of Beamer telling its PPT made.Because Beamer speaks louder. Beamer(LaTeX) and Powerpoint are two different world's, better don't try convert/join them, it's efficiency is poor. However see [How should I convert my beamer slides to PowerPoint according to these odd specifications?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9462/15717)

Comment: With a bit of elbow grease, you may be able to fake it for sufficiently simple purposes: use a whole-page image of their page as the background (really, that's much easier than re-doing all the gradients and spacing), and then adjust fonts and position for the content. I don't know if that's worth the effort...

Comment: If your Powerpoint template is not too much elaborated, you can build a new Beamer theme from that; you may follow as a preliminary step [How do I customize Beamer template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54577/13304) and then having a look to the code of some [nice Beamer themes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15067/13304).

Comment: I'll try Ulrich's suggestion - thanks. I just cannot face using Powerpoint...

Comment: In Louis' answer to [Any way of converting ppt or odf to beamer or org?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66314/1952) there is some VBA code which translates a ppt file to beamer. Background and graphics are converted to png files. I've used several times and it's useful as starting point.

Comment: I've closed this as 'too broad'. There is no simple tool to do this, and taking a completely arbitrary case is potentially a _lot_ of work. As it stands, that's really too big a job for a question here.

Comment: You can do it manually, as I did with the Median theme: [beamerports](https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports)