# How to convert a Powerpoint template to a Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, powerpoint

***Fore note***: there is [a closed question with a similar title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102580/43055), I hope my case is narrow enough to warrant acceptance.

The institute has changed name and image; a new batch of logos and powerpoints templates is out. So far I have used a beamer theme with the old image produced by a savvy colleague that no longer works here. I have no Microsoft software installed, the only programme that opens `pptx` files is Libre Office Impress, of which I know very little and struggle to work with.

As far as I understand from Impress, the template is composed by a background image, a set of font definitions, and title placing in the first page. What would be the easiest/best way of creating a beamer theme from it?

**Update**: I do not wish to create a new theme from scratch. I wish to find a method or tool to transform an existing Powerpoint template into a Beamer theme.

Comment: If you have an existing template, the easiest way is hard-code changing the images. I ported my university PowerPoint theme to `beamer`, but it was very difficult and long. But that question is too generic! We have no idea of what is the `beamer` theme code of your colleague, nor we know in details what changes are required.

Comment: Why is the old theme relevant here? It is very different from the new template and I will soon stop using it.

Comment: You said "The institute has changed name and image", so I thought there were differences only in that, not in the structure of the theme. Templates in `beamer` are far more complex than PowerPoint. If you read italian, [this guide](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.guitex.org%2Fhome%2Fimages%2Fdoc%2FGuideGuIT%2Fintropersbeamer.pdf&ei=3WGRVJqPNIe7Pb_bgbAM&usg=AFQjCNGJ-Dm-AQFPLHFX4WnI3H1AYS5pvg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.ZWU) is wonderful. Nevertheless, it take to me about a month to create the `beamer` theme from scratch.

Comment: There is no general procedure or automatic converter as far as I know. The conversion may be more or less complicated depending on the ppt template. If you post a screenshot of the ppt template we might be able to tell you how much work is needed for the conversion, but that will be only relevant for the specific template, not for "ppt templates in general".

Comment: I see why the edit was made, but can also see why the question was closed. There simply isn't a way to take a PowerPoint layout and convert it to a `beamer` one, so it will come down to doing something from scratch in code terms (even though the design has been drawn already).

Comment: Imagine there is a kid somewhere working on something like it in his attic. Why should not he be able to post his method/tool to this question?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: Until such a kid shows their face (which might be in 1,234 days, or just over 3 years, say, perhaps sooner, perhaps later) we can leave this question closed. That kid, upon arrival, could request this be opened at that time.

Comment: A new user [is not able to re-open questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question). You may wish to close or delete this question, just please do not mark it as a duplicate, because it is not. Cheers.